# Why does my generated JSON have too many "\\"?

Tags: json, windows, powershell, web-deployment

I have a Powershell Script which generates a JSON file with data in it.

I have a problem with this file though. It generates double the amount of "\"!

Do you know how I could solve this?

Here is my Code to generate the JSON File:

```
[ordered]@{
pcname='ENTER HERE';
share='\\ENTER HERE\C$';
filename='ENTER HERE';
destfilepath='some\folder';
destfile='$in.share\$in.destfilepath\$in.filename';
RDdestfile='C:\$in.destfilepath\';
Username="ENTER HERE";
Password="ENTER HERE";
EncryptedPassword=""
} | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File "$secFile"
```

$secFile is just a path to save the file to. Just tell me if you need this too.

The output JSON file looks liek this though:

```
{
"pcname": "ENTER HERE",
"share": "\\\\ENTER HERE\\C$",
"filename": "ENTER HERE",
"destfilepath": "some\\folder",
"destfile": "$in.share\\$in.destfilepath\\$in.filename",
"RDdestfile": "C:\\$in.destfilepath\\",
"Username": "ENTER HERE",
"Password": "ENTER HERE",
"EncryptedPassword": ""
}
```

Greetings

Martin

Edit: I also posted this question in the PowerShell.org Forum and the Microsoft Tech Community, just so you know

https://powershell.org/forums/topic/why-does-my-generated-json-have-too-many/

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-powershell/why-does-my-generated-json-have-too-many-quot-quot/td-p/1592234

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to escape the JSON:

```
[ordered]@{
pcname='ENTER HERE';
share='\\ENTER HERE\C$';
filename='ENTER HERE';
destfilepath='some\folder';
destfile='$in.share\$in.destfilepath\$in.filename';
RDdestfile='C:\$in.destfilepath\';
Username="ENTER HERE";
Password="ENTER HERE";
EncryptedPassword=""
} | ConvertTo-Json | Foreach {[System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_)} | Out-File "$secFile"
```

This will make the backslashes escape. Output:

```
{
    "pcname":  "ENTER HERE",
    "share":  "\\ENTER HERE\C$",
    "filename":  "ENTER HERE",
    "destfilepath":  "some\folder",
    "destfile":  "$in.share\$in.destfilepath\$in.filename",
    "RDdestfile":  "C:\$in.destfilepath\",
    "Username":  "ENTER HERE",
    "Password":  "ENTER HERE",
    "EncryptedPassword":  ""
}
```

Comment: But now I have the problem that when I convert it from JSON and back to json it enters all values as null... Any idea why that could be?

Comment: Because it's invalid JSON, so acttually **not** JSON.

Comment: Yes @RobbyCornelissen you are right, still to fit the user's needs, I have posted this solution.

Answer (score 3):

That's the correct number of backslashes for the content you have.

In a JSON string, a backslash (`\`) needs to be escaped with another backslash (`\\`).

Comment: Ok, ok this really helped me, thanks a lot! I still have a problem though... I have many parts where I only want one backslash. How would I reach that? Greetings

Comment: If you want valid JSON, you can't. But if you parse the content with a JSON parser, it will be parsed correctly, i.e. the backslashes will be unescaped again.

Comment: Thanks again for your comment!
I wanted to ask how I can parse JSON, because I am not good in JSON and also not especially good in powershell... 
 And also would I still be able to convert it from json back to normal using powershell? (ConvertFrom-Json) Greetings

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/playing-with-json-and-powershell/